# How to pass an EntityReference to add attribute value on a lookup field in Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi, entityreference

```
Entity contact = new Entity("contact");
contact.Attributes.Add("fullname", "h api test");
contact.Attributes.Add("emailaddress1", "hh@devenv1.local");
contact.Attributes.Add("telephone1", "1");

contact.Attributes["parentcusotmerid"] = new EntityReference("Organization", );

Guid contactId = m_OrgServ.Create(contact);
Console.WriteLine(contactId);
```

[The lookup field I want to set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avbg3.png)

The logicalname of the lookup field is `parentcusotmerid`, and

```
m_OrgSerc.create
```

is basically

```
Service.create
```

I am setting attribute values for the fields, it works fine for normal text boxes where I am entering values, however for lookup values it doesn't work. I know lookup fields are of type `EntityReference`, so I need to know the `LogicalName` of the entity the lookup is pointing and the `Id` of the record.

I have tried it but its asking for the GUID of the Organization field now, so I'm not sure if I am going about it the right way?

Comment: "parentcustomerid" is a lookup to account and contact so you have to use either of the entities logical name to assign lookup value. If you have renamed the account entity to organization then its only the display name which is changed the schema name remains the same. Are you trying associated account record with the current contact?

Comment: @Nitin   I am just trying to create a contact... so I want to set the lookup field to a value. The organization is already created, I just want to associate that to this contact that I am creating. Sorry is this what you were asking ?

Comment: @HH44 You cannot set "parentcustomerid" to organization. It's special reference field that takes either Account or Contact entity reference as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set "parentcustomerid" to organization. It's special reference field that takes either Account or Contact entity reference as parameter.

If you want to set it you go like this

```
contact.Attributes["parentcusotmerid"] = new EntityReference("account", Guid.NewGuid());
```

or

```
contact.Attributes["parentcusotmerid"] = new EntityReference("contact", Guid.NewGuid());
```

where Guid.NewGuid() is Guid of your Account or Contact that you want to reference

Comment: But as you can see from the image I have upload .. I want to set the "organization name" field which is "parentcustomerid" to the value "BAE Systems plc" ... so where in this code that you have given can I specify that .. so that is the value that is looked at and chosen ?

Comment: @HH44 you renamed the parent customer lookup as organisation, if you already created the “BAE systems” account record, you have to get the guid of that record. The guid with entity reference is the only way to set it. We cannot set with just name.

Comment: As Arun said you would set referenz to Account with the GUID of the BAE systems record if it already exists